# Resizing Movie Clip with MoviePy leads to SIGKILL on m1 mac

Tags: python, macos, apple-m1, moviepy

I'm trying to resize a movie clip using moviepy, but I'm getting a sigkill every time. I've run it on two clips, several times, it seems consistent.

```
Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)
```

Reading and writing mp4 files. The source file's info says:

```
Dimensions: 1280 × 720
codecs: Timecode, MPEG-4 AAC, H.264
color profile: HD (1-1-1)
```

It's a canon camcorder for the source, if that adds any information.

I was able to resize with ffmpeg directly.

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile.MP4   -ss 00:14:09 -vf "scale=iw*0.5:ih*0.5" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict experimental output_video.mp4
```

I'm on an an M1 mac, 13.2.1, moviepy 1.03

```
    with moviepy.editor.VideoFileClip(abs_path) as video:
        subclip = video.subclip(args.start, args.end)
        subclip.resize(640, 480)
```

Comment: I just tried without the subclip, it still failed.

Comment: It is likely a OOM (out of memory) condition causing the kernel to kill your process. Run the Activity Monitor app and monitor memory usage.